# how to remove junk characters in json_encode

Tags: json

I am trying to create a search auto fill in opencart site.

I have put the sql queries and everything is working well, but when I json-encoded the result rows I am getting a result like this:

```
[{key:value},{key:value}]��Smo�0��� ��� A�n�ԥ��MӴ/ۤv�����ؙ}�V��}�(t��d���<��y\�5����ƹ�����p!�H�*Δ�!L�ܵ,Sδ� �հ�|�tY� UQ!�T �w�����b�m��lW�"�
```

I have to remove all those junk characters and get only the valid json.
How can I accomplish the task? I have tried `charset utf-8` blah blah blah... But no use!

Could someone please help me to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly you are using php. If yes then following are your options.

Option 1: use iconv() to convert your results to UTF-8 before feeding them to json_encode.

Option 2: mysqli_set_charset($data, 'utf8');

Alternatively you can ensure that your data is in UTF-8 and your database connection uses UTF-8 as well

Option 3: Try to save the file as 'UTF-8 without BOM'.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. but even without any sql query i am getting this like junk response.. for example in function(){ echo "helo";} am getting resopnse like helo..(then those junks) :( and yes am using php

Comment: Then its the problem with saving your file. Try to save the file as 'UTF-8 without BOM'.  If still facing issue share your editor details and will try to further help you how to save file .

Comment: No problem.. I have updated my answer too so of will help people reading in future :)

Comment: am very beginner to php and it using mvcl framework .. could you please guide me how to save the file in utf-8 format... if you need i wil give the codes in the controller file thanks for reply

Comment: sorry but am using simple notpad via vnc viewer in my ubuntu vps

Comment: and yes when in notepadeqq i can see option to save as utf and as utf-8 without BOM etc shall i choose them ??????

Comment: am very sorry but it didnt work ... i saved both the model and controller php files as utf without bom but still getting those junks :(

Comment: Hmmm.... This should work.  Try creating  new file and paste your code there and retry. Download notpad++ and retry same steps....n If that doesn't work try option 1 and 2 for time being ...

Comment: helo finally got it worked .. i have changed some lines in my controller ... instead echo $this_model_mymodel->function() i put it like $var = $this_model_mymodel->function(); return $var;  and now i got it without those junks ....anyway very very thanks.... for helping me :)